# Why do I have to click the anchor point after every curve using the pen tool illustrator how do I fix it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I use the pen tool a lot and I hate the fact that if I draw around an image I have to constantly keep clicking the anchor point after every point to reset the position.

The issue is I sometime miss click the anchor point because it is so small and end up having to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> everything to go back and start again from that point. If I haven't noticed it sometimes I have to delete several points and start again or play around with the point.

Is there a way to make it so that I can draw around an image without having to reset the points each time by clicking the anchor and no I refuse to draw the shape then fix the points later it is too time-consuming. I would like to know if you can draw with the pen tool with only 1 click for each point without having to edit the point after?

Comment: ermm.. it only takes 1 click to set an anchor.. then the next click connects to the last anchor. No clue why you feel you *must* click every anchor twice. More specitivity would help. The only time you need to click an anchors again are A) you've deselected the path and then reselected it or B) you want to break the symmetry of a smooth point. -- I constantly just click click click-drag click click click-drag and never hit an anchor twice.

Comment: Also, if the anchors are too small go to preferences and make them bigger.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re describing here at all. What do you mean by “clicking the anchor point to reset the position”? Reset what position? To what?

Comment: There's probably something you aren't getting about using the Pen tool. What you are describing sounds a bit strange TBH. Clicking on anchors again after you've made them is not something I've ever had to do, except when making further minor adjustments after completing a path. Maybe try the [Bézier Game](https://bezier.method.ac/) for tuition and practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fatal error somewhere or you use the same words as we, but for you many of them mean different things than for us.

In the next image the greyish rectangle with a greenish shape is a raster image, it's not a vector. I decided to use the pen and draw a red path around the greenish part.

[image]

In the left the job was not started.

The 2nd version shows what I got by clicking three times with the pen. The first click was made on the left bottom corner of the greenish shape.

The 3rd version is got by clicking one time more and at the same time by dragging the handle out of the node to get a curve.

The rightmost version has got 4 clicks more. The last click was made on the starting corner to close the curve.

Answer (score 0):

When you get enough practice with the pen you wouldn't have to reset a lot.

I think going to preferences> Selection & Anchor Display> and making the anchor points as big as it allows will make things very easy. Surely you can't miss it that way.

[image]